# Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of ... Angular 16

Tags: angular, binding

man, Angular docs and tutorials suck...

I´m getting a "Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of ..." error in the button:

```
  import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
  import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
  import { PropertyLocation } from '../property-location';
  import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-property-listing',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
    template: `
      <div>
        <img
          [src]="propertyLocation.img"
          alt="photo of {{ propertyLocation.name }}" />
        <h2>{{ propertyLocation.name }}</h2>
        <p>{{ propertyLocation.city }}, {{ propertyLocation.province }}</p>
        <button [routerLink]="['/details', propertyLocation.id]">
          View More
        </button>
      </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./property-listing.component.css'],
  })
  export class PropertyListingComponent {
    @Input() propertyLocation!: PropertyLocation;
  }
```

I´ve followed the first app tutorial from Angular step by step. Here´s the routes:

```
  import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
  import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
  import { DetailsComponent } from './details/details.component';

  const routeConfig: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent,
      title: 'Home',
    },
    {
      path: 'details/:id',
      component: DetailsComponent,
      title: 'Details',
    },
  ];

  export default routeConfig;
```

And here´s my main.ts:

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

And app.config.ts:

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import routeConfig from './routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routeConfig)],
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you setup your `main.ts` file? Could you update your question to include one?

Comment: Can you post your module file? If it can't use routerLink, then you are missing the CommonModule I believe.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz repro of your issue ? The code you shared works fine, the routerLink directive is exported by the RouterModule and you importer the RouterModule.

Comment: @skouch2022 I updated the question with the main.ts, do you see anything missing?

Comment: Another thing is that it´s working fine, just throwing the error there

Comment: Hmmm..., I don't see anything standout there. What editor do you use to compile your code? Is it Local Angular CLI? or something online?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure, but I think that `[routerLink]` can be used **only** with `<a>` tag, not with buttons. If you want to use a button, inject [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) in your constructor and use navigate or navigateByUrl method. NOTE: routerLinkActive can be applied to any html tag